# How can I jump to an item of a list view in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have an application where I have one edittext. And also I have one listview that is populated with 100 items and can show only 5 items at a time. I enter a number (n) in the Edittext and I want listview to jump to the n th item of the list view and that n th item should come at the top of the viewable area (the one that shows 5 listview items). Can you please tell me how this can be achieved..

Answer (score 10):

A call to [setSelection(position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29) should do the trick.

Comment: I tried to do the same but it only worked when i m using the array adapter, when i m using the Base adapter, setSelection(position) is not working. Is it like this or i m doing something wrong??

Comment: @shashi What do you mean? BaseAdapter is abstract.

Comment: sorry it was my fault.. i was doing it wrong way .. and thanks for the Answer